# How can I send an integer array in Photonview.RPC call

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I am trying to send an array of integers across the network to a photonplayer and I cant figure out how can i send an array. this is my method and it doesn't work.

`photonView.RPC("RPC_Method", player, array)`

and how do i receive it?

`RPC_Method(int[] array)`

do i need to convert it to a string or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting your array to object:

```
photonView.RPC("RPC_Method", player, (object)array);
```